# file recurse change very slow in puppet

Tags: content-management-system, puppet

```
  file { '/opt/graphite/storage':
    ensure  => directory,
    recurse => true,
    owner   => 'www-data',
    group   => 'www-data',
  }
```

I have about 50G files in '/opt/graphite/storage' directory.

And it took about 300 seconds to finish this puppet code.

Is there a way I can speed up it?

checksum => none didn't fix my problem...

Comment: I think it simply executes: chown www-data:www-data -R /opt/graphite/storage , how much time does it take on your 50G directory?

Comment: take a look at [this suggested solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16049356/547020).

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure there's no way around this. Bottom line is puppet sucks at recursively setting permissions/attributes on a **large** directory tree.

You might be better off setting these permissions in a cronjob, or if you're looking for *immediate* updates, create a separate exec to take care of this.